# PYTHON - Error while using numpy genfromtxt to import csv data with multiple data types

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, numpy, data-mining

I'm working on a kaggle competition to predict restaurant revenue based on multiple predictors. I'm a beginner user of Python, I would normally use Rapidminer for data analysis. I am using Python 3.4 on the Spyder 2.3 dev environment.

I am using the below code to import the training csv file.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from numpy import genfromtxt, savetxt

  def main():
      #create the training & test sets, skipping the header row with [1:]
      dataset = genfromtxt(open('data/train.csv','rb'), delimiter=",", dtype= None)[1:]   
      train = [x[1:41] for x in dataset]
      test = genfromtxt(open('data/test.csv','rb'), delimiter=",")[1:]
```

This is the error I get:

```
dataset = genfromtxt(open('data/train.csv','rb'), delimiter=",", dtype= None)[1:]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Then I checked for various imported data types using `print (dataset.dtype)`

I noticed that the datatypes had been individually assigned for every value in the csv file. Moreover, the code wouldn't work with [1:] in the end. It gave me the same error of `too many indices`. And if I removed [1:] and defined the input with the `skip_header=1` option, I got the below error:

```
output = np.array(data, dtype=ddtype)

TypeError: Empty data-type
```

It seems to me like the entire data set is being read as a single row with over 5000 columns.

The data set consists of 43 columns and 138 rows.

I'm stuck at this point, I would appreciate any help with how I can proceed.

I'm posting the raw csv data below (a sample):

```
Id,Open Date,City,City Group,Type,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,P10,P11,P12,P13,P14,P15,P16,P17,P18,P19,P20,P21,P22,P23,P24,P25,P26,P27,P28,P29,P30,P31,P32,P33,P34,P35,P36,P37,revenue
0,7/17/99,Ä°stanbul,Big Cities,IL,4,5,4,4,2,2,5,4,5,5,3,5,5,1,2,2,2,4,5,4,1,3,3,1,1,1,4,2,3,5,3,4,5,5,4,3,4,5653753
1,2/14/08,Ankara,Big Cities,FC,4,5,4,4,1,2,5,5,5,5,1,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,3,2,1,3,2,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6923131
2,3/9/13,DiyarbakÄr,Other,IL,2,4,2,5,2,3,5,5,5,5,2,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2055379
3,2/2/12,Tokat,Other,IL,6,4.5,6,6,4,4,10,8,10,10,8,10,7.5,6,4,9,3,12,20,12,6,1,10,2,2,2.5,2.5,2.5,7.5,25,12,10,6,18,12,12,6,2675511
4,5/9/09,Gaziantep,Other,IL,3,4,3,4,2,2,5,5,5,5,2,5,5,2,1,2,1,4,2,2,1,2,1,2,3,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,2,3,4,3,3,4316715
5,2/12/10,Ankara,Big Cities,FC,6,6,4.5,7.5,8,10,10,8,8,8,10,8,6,0,0,0,0,0,5,6,3,1,5,0,0,0,0,7.5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5017319
6,10/11/10,Ä°stanbul,Big Cities,IL,2,3,4,4,1,5,5,5,5,5,2,5,5,3,4,4,3,4,2,4,1,2,1,5,4,4,5,1,3,4,5,2,2,3,5,4,4,5166635
7,6/21/11,Ä°stanbul,Big Cities,IL,4,5,4,5,2,3,5,4,4,4,4,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,3,5,2,4,2,0,0,0,0,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4491607
8,8/28/10,Afyonkarahisar,Other,IL,1,1,4,4,1,2,1,5,5,5,1,5,5,1,1,2,1,4,1,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,2,2,3,4,5,5,3,4,5,4,5,4952497
9,11/16/11,Edirne,Other,IL,6,4.5,6,7.5,6,4,10,10,10,10,2,10,7.5,0,0,0,0,0,25,3,3,1,10,0,0,0,0,5,2.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5444227
```

Comment: Post the raw input data, enough to allow use to reproduce the error, it's likely that you've not supplied sufficient information to the parser to parse the data rather than the data is duff

Comment: Your csv worked for me can you post your python and numpy version, mine is python 3.4 64-bit numpy '1.9.2rc1'

Comment: python 3.4 64-bit and numpy 1.9.0

Comment: My guess is that somewhere in your csv data, there's a formatting problem of some sort: perhaps two lines merged into one, or a line with a terminal `,`, or a line with an extra column. The error is not in your sample data, though, so we're not seeing the same problems.

Comment: Try opening the file in text mode, not binary: `open('data/train.csv','r')`

Comment: So changing to 'r' instead of 'rb' worked. But I'm getting this error now:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 191: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: `x=np.genfromtxt('stack29334205.txt', delimiter="," ,names=True, dtype=None)` gives me 10 rows, 43 item dtype, with a mix of  ints, floats and strings. (python3)

Answer (score 0):

I think the characters (e.g. Ä°) are causing the problem in genfromtxt. I found the following reads in the data you have here,

```
dtypes = "i8,S12,S12,S12,S12" + ",i8"*38
test = genfromtxt(open('data/test.csv','rb'),  delimiter="," , names = True, dtype=dtypes)
```

You can then access the elements by name,

```
In [16]: test['P8']
Out[16]: array([ 4,  5,  5,  8,  5,  8,  5,  4,  5, 10])
```

The values for the city column,

```
test['City']
```

returns,

```
array(['\xc3\x84\xc2\xb0stanbul', 'Ankara', 'Diyarbak\xc3\x84r', 'Tokat',
   'Gaziantep', 'Ankara', '\xc3\x84\xc2\xb0stanbul',
   '\xc3\x84\xc2\xb0stanbul', 'Afyonkarahis', 'Edirne'], 
  dtype='|S12')
```

In principle, you could try to convert these to unicode in your python script with something like,

```
In [17]: unicode(test['City'][0], 'utf8')
Out[17]: u'\xc4\xb0stanbul
```

Where \xc4\xb0 is UTF-8 hexadecimal encoding for İ. To avoid this, you could also try to clean up the csv input files.

Comment: So is there a way to clean up the CSV file using python? Or do I have to do this manually outside?

Comment: You could read it as above (genfromtxt), use some form of transliteration, e.g. https://github.com/iki/unidecode and write back (`savetxt("test_nouni.csv", dataset, delimiter=",")`. You would lose any unicode characters but it may make life easier. It depends on how you plan to use the data, personally I'd keep the city names in the same format as you read them (assuming they are consistent) and convert only when you need to output for a user...

Answer (score 0):

[Solved].

I just chucked numpy's genfromtext and opted to use read_csv from pandas since it gives the option to import text in 'utf-8' encoding.